# Extend the hyperref link to Figure and a, b, c

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am looking for a solution to extend the `hyperref` link  for a figure, a chapter, etc. to the word "Figure", (or "Chapter") beforehand and the picture subindex a, b, c, etc. present in the figure itself afterhand, using a single function that could be written for example `\ref[Figure][a]{missing Figure}`. Anyway to do this ?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
   \missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{a: Missing figure, and b: still missing figure.}
\label{fig:missing Figure}
\end{figure}

Something in Figure \ref{fig:missing Figure} a and some other thing in Figure \ref{fig:missing Figure} b.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\hyperref` with the optional argument can be used to link to labels with arbitray text:

```
\hyperref[<label>]{<arbitrary text>}
```

The star form `\ref*` sets a reference without additional link, since the link is already set by `\hyperref`.

The following example defines `\figref` for figure references. The optional argument takes the subfigure number, the mandatory argument the label name without prefix `fig:`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\figref}[2][]{%
  \hyperref[{fig:#2}]{%
    Figure~\ref*{fig:#2}%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
    \else
      \,#1%
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
   \missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{a: Missing figure, and b: still missing figure.}
\label{fig:missing Figure}
\end{figure}

The figure \figref{missing Figure} contains two subfigures.
Something in \figref[a]{missing Figure} and some other thing in
Figure \figref[b]{missing Figure}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Version as generic command form via `\myref` (I do not recommend redefining `\ref`):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{twoopt}

\newcommandtwoopt*{\myref}[3][][]{%
  \hyperref[{#3}]{%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
    \else
      #1~%
    \fi
    \ref*{#3}%
    \ifx\\#2\\%
    \else
      \,#2%
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
   \missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{a: Missing figure, and b: still missing figure.}
\label{fig:missing Figure}
\end{figure}

The figure \myref[Figure]{fig:missing Figure} contains two subfigures.
Something in \myref[Figure][a]{fig:missing Figure} and some other thing in
Figure \myref[Figure][b]{fig:missing Figure}.

\end{document}
```

### `\eqref`

A star form `\eqref` is not provided, but something like `(\ref*{...})` can be used instead. Or more precise, `\eqref` is defined in package `amsmath` as:

```
\newcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
```

Then `\eqrefstar` without link can be defined as:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\eqrefstar}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed, this is almost what I want. Although, I was more looking for something that could take the word "Figure" as an optionnal argument so I could use the same function for anything. By the way, is there an easy way to extend it to \eqref ? \eqref* does not seem to work.

Comment: That eqref comment will not give upright ()s. It is "fairly" simple to combine the hyperref command and eqref.

Comment: @daleif I have added a definition for `\eqrefstar`, a `\eqref` without link.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Heiko and the others. That is perfect. This is just to add eqref to the answer:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{twoopt}

\newcommandtwoopt*{\myeqref}[3][][]{%
  \hyperref[{#3}]{%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
      Equation~%
    \else
      #1~%
    \fi
    (\ref*{#3})%
    \ifx\\#2\\%
    \else
      \,#2%
    \fi
  }%
}
\begin{document}

See \myeqref{eq:plancksrelation} (\myeqref[Relation][a]{eq:plancksrelation}) for details.

\begin{equation}
E = \hbar \omega
\label{eq:plancksrelation}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```