# Having showkeys to work nicely with custom \ref command

Tags: hyperref, showkeys

I used a customized command `\myref` (From a previous question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266434/extend-the-hyperref-link-to-figure-and-a-b-c)) that allows me to include in the hyperref link the word, say, Equation, before the reference. Unfortunatly, it does not seems to happy when used with `\usepackage{showkeys}`, especially when labels contain math symboles like underscores.

Is there a possible fix for the code that would allow then to work nicely together ?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{twoopt}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue} 

\newcommandtwoopt*{\myref}[3][][]{%
  \hyperref[{#3}]{%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
    \else
      #1~%
    \fi
    \ref*{#3}%
    \ifx\\#2\\%
    \else
      \,#2%
    \fi
  }%
}

\usepackage{showkeys} 
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x - 3 = 7
\label{eq:too_complicated}
\end{equation}

\myref[Equation]{eq:too_complicated} is so complicated that it does not admit any analytical solution.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order of the calls (`hyperref`should be the last package to be called!)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{showkeys} % <========================================
\usepackage{twoopt}   % <========================================
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{twoopt}  % <========================================
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue} 

\newcommandtwoopt*{\myref}[3][][]{%
  \hyperref[{#3}]{%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
    \else
      #1~%
    \fi
    \ref*{#3}%
    \ifx\\#2\\%
    \else
      \,#2%
    \fi
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x - 3 = 7
\label{eq:too_complicated}
\end{equation}

\myref[Equation]{eq:too_complicated} is so complicated that it does not admit any analytical solution.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure to understand why it works, but it does ... Thanks a lot !