# How to get cross-references to multiple figures?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, labels

[image]

I'm preparing my manuscript for a journal in which figures are in the following clickable format like, for exapmle, "Fig. 1", "Figs. 2 and 3" and "Figs. 4-6". I'm trying to use the same environment of `\hyperref` as given in the [existing code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266434/extend-the-hyperref-link-to-figure-and-a-b-c) provided by [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek), but not getting the required format. Please have a look on the attached screenshot for figure referencing style. The MWE is copied from [existing code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266434/extend-the-hyperref-link-to-figure-and-a-b-c),

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\figref}[2][]{%
\hyperref[{fig:#2}]{%
Fig.~\ref*{fig:#2}%
\ifx\\#1\\%
\else
\,#1%
\fi
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{Missing figure 1.}
\label{fig:missing Figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{Missing figure 2.}
\label{fig:missing Figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{Missing figure 3.}
\label{fig:missing Figure3}
\end{figure}

The single figure should be like that \figref{missing Figure1}.
And two figures be like that \figref{missing Figure1} and \figref{missing Figure2}, 
moreover the combination of three figures like tha \figref{missing Figure1, 
missing Figure2,missing Figure3} as you can see in the attached journal's 
screenshot.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  Can you please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Quick solution without getting more information: `\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}` followed by `\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}` and use `\cref` instead of `\ref` etc.

Comment: @hooy, Nice reply, it works, but I want get "Figs.1-3" instead of "Figs.1 to 3". Similarly "Figs.1 and 2", in which "and" should also be clickable.

Comment: @kamran See my answer below. Also, it does not really make sense to have "and" clickable. Which of the figures should this link to? I'd keep "and" out from any links, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: @hooy, Thanks for your answer below, It seems to be an excellent, but it is a journals' requirement that's why I've attached a screenshot in my question.

Comment: The screenshot you've posted practices weirdly inconsistent highlighting of the hyperlinks: "Fig", "Figs.", and "Table" would all appear to be part of the respective hyperlinks, where "Eqs." is not. A separate concern: Making the conjunction particles ("and" and en-dash) parts of the hyperlinks is rather questionable. For instance, where exactly is the "and" in "Figs. 3 and 4" supposed to point to: to Figure 3, to Figure 4, or maybe (but hopefully not) to somewhere else?

Comment: @Mico, I just noted in the original .pdf of screenshot, "and" is just pointing to "Fig. 3" only one of them. I agreed with your reply. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a poor idea, typographically speaking, to make the conjunction particle -- "and", "to", "`--`" (en-dash), etc. -- a part of the hyperlink.

The following adaptations to the `cleveref` package may be what you're looking for. Observe that a range of cross-referenced items can be specified either via `\Cref` or via `\Crefrange`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{--}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\caption{Missing figure 1.}\label{fig:1}
\caption{Missing figure 2.}\label{fig:2}
\caption{Missing figure 3.}\label{fig:3}
\caption{Missing figure 4.}\label{fig:4}
\caption{Missing figure 5.}\label{fig:5}
\end{figure}

\obeylines % just for this example
Single figure: \Cref{fig:2}
Two figures: \Cref{fig:1,fig:3}
Range of consecutive figures: \Cref{fig:1,fig:2,fig:3}, \Crefrange{fig:1}{fig:5}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cleveref`package for this, along with some options for both `hyperref` and `cleveref`. With minor changes to the referencing commands used, that is, replace `\figref` with `\cref` and `\crefrange` where appropriate.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}

\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{Missing figure 1.}
\label{fig:missing Figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{Missing figure 2.}
\label{fig:missing Figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
\caption{Missing figure 3.}
\label{fig:missing Figure3}
\end{figure}
The single figure should be like that \cref{fig:missing Figure1}. And two figures be like that \cref{fig:missing Figure1,fig:missing Figure2}, moreover the combination of three figures like the \crefrange{fig:missing Figure1}{fig:missing Figure3} as you can see in the attached journal's screenshot.

\end{document}
```

This gives the output:

> [image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new command called multiref and supply it the first and last figures

```
\newcommand{\multiref}[2]{\autoref{#1}-\ref{#2}} % from - to
```

Usage:

```
\multiref{fig:startfiglabel}{fig:endfiglabel}
```

This gives `Figure 2-5` if your figure locations are the second and fifth figures.

Comment: I like this but it should use doubled -- for from - to, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3821/171999