# How to use \ref{} command with a list of figures?

Tags: captions, citing, ref

I need to use `\ref{}` command with a list of figures. So, instead of using the command multiple times as follows:

```
Figures \ref{fig:1}, \ref{fig:2}, and \ref{fig:3}
%the output will be Figures 1,2 and 3.
```

I need to use it one time to refer to a list of figures, so the required output looks like `Figures 1-3`.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer to my question in this link [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371622/how-to-get-cross-references-to-multiple-figures) by using the three lines as below:

```
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
%Crefname will write the appropriate format for the word "figure"
\newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{--}
%to change "to" to dsah "-"
%example
\Crefrange{fig:1}{fig:5}
%the output will be like: Figs 1-5
```