# How to have light blue hyperref colour?

Tags: hyperref

Consider this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960077922011948

How do we achieve this light blue colour for links?

From the answer to this question: [Extend the hyperref link to Figure and a, b, c](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266434/extend-the-hyperref-link-to-figure-and-a-b-c):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
    
    \newcommand*{\figref}[2][]{%
      \hyperref[{fig:#2}]{%
        Figure~\ref*{fig:#2}%
        \ifx\\#1\\%
        \else
          \,#1%
        \fi
      }%
    }
    
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
\chapter{one}
    
    \begin{figure}[t]
       \missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
    \caption{a: Missing figure, and b: still missing figure.}
    \label{fig:missing Figure}
    \end{figure}
    
    The figure \figref{missing Figure} contains two subfigures.
    Something in \figref[a]{missing Figure} and some other thing in
    Figure \figref[b]{missing Figure}.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: See manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref, ch. 7.20, which directs you to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hycolor . // See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperref+color .

Comment: @MS-SPO I had a look but couldn't figure it out. I have the normal blue working but cant get the light blue.

Comment: @Math Please add a small, but compilable test document to your question so we can see how far you got.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Added in.

Comment: `\usepackage{hycolor}`, use the color picker tool of any bitmap editor, set it using `\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=[rgb]{1,0,0}}` , see p. 2 in said manual, where 1 probably corresponds to 255 in ordinary RGB-speak. (And check the hyperref manual again, taking the next comment into account ...)

Comment: @Math Your code does not produce "normal blue" links

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz My bad, I just edited.

Comment: @MS-SPO could you try it then answer below?

Comment: load xcolor (todonotes does it already), define a lightblue color and then use linkcolor=lightblue

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah, I used `\hypersetup{linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.5,0.73}}` which is my closest match. If someone can do better, feel free to comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently you solved your problem yourself, taking together your code and last comment ... which can be easily verified by using instead for some pinkish:

```
\hypersetup{linkcolor=[rgb]{1,0.5,0.73}}% ;-)
```

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
    
    \newcommand*{\figref}[2][]{%
      \hyperref[{fig:#2}]{%
        Figure~\ref*{fig:#2}%
        \ifx\\#1\\%
        \else
          \,#1%
        \fi
      }%
    }
    
\begin{document}
%\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.5,0.73}}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\chapter{one}
    
    \begin{figure}[t]
       \missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{- << Ciel, mon mari >> dit-elle !}
    \caption{a: Missing figure, and b: still missing figure.}
    \label{fig:missing Figure}
    \end{figure}
    
    The figure \figref{missing Figure} contains two subfigures.
    Something in \figref[a]{missing Figure} and some other thing in
    Figure \figref[b]{missing Figure}.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it helped me solve the problem :)

Comment: Thanks as well :)